# Reference count of ComPtr returned from a factory method is incremented twice

Tags: c++, com, wrl

I declared a `COM` interface and I have two implementations(classes) of the interface depending on input config. I also have a factory method that checks for input config and appropriately calls NEW on the class. In my class I implement `AddRef()` and `Release()` as per `COM` spec.
I declare a `ComPtr` and call the factory method to get access to above interface. I can do this two ways,

1) Return ComPtr from Factory method

```
ComPtr<ICaptureSource> ICaptureSource::CreateInstance(someConfig)
{
   switch (someConfig)
   {
     case 1:
          return (new CCaptureSource1());  >> Ref count in this class is initialized to 1 
          break;
     case 2:
          return (new CCaptureSource2());  >> Ref count in this class is initialized to 1 
           break;
     default:
          return nullptr;
   }

}


ComPtr <ICaptureSource> captureSource;

captureSource = ICaptureSource::CreateInstance(someConfig);
```

After returning from above call, Ref count of `captureSource` is '2'. I was expecting it to be 1.

However with below code, Ref count is 1

2) Pass `ComPtr` address as parameter to factory method

```
HRESULT ICaptureSource::CreateInstance(someConfig, ICapturesource **ppv)
{
   ICaptureSource *pTemp = nullptr;
   switch (someConfig)
   {
     case 1:
          pTemp = new CCaptureSource1();  >> Ref count in this class is initialized to 1 
          break;
     case 2:
          pTemp = new CCaptureSource2();  >> Ref count in this class is initialized to 1 
           break;
   }

  if (SUCCEEDED(hr) && (ppv != nullptr))
  {
     *ppv = pTemp;
  }
  return hr
}
```

```
ComPtr <ICaptureSource> captureSource;

hr = ICaptureSource::CreateInstance(someConfig, &captureSource);
```

`captureSource` ref count is now 1.

Kindly guide me why is there a difference in ref count in above two approaches and why returning an object is incrementing ref count (2), Vs setting object pointer to `*ppv`  (ref count 1).

As it can be expected, approach (1) is causing memleak because ref count does not go to 0.

Comment: Can you add the source for `CCaptureSource1` as well?

Comment: Apparently the CCaptureSourcex constructor initializes the reference count to 1.  That is not terribly unusual, but the ComPtr constructor increments the count.  Consider using ComPtr::Attach().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WRL [`ComPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cppcx/wrl/comptr-class?view=vs-2019) instance is automatically incrementing reference counter at the moment your

`new CCaptureSource1()`

is converted to returned

`ComPtr<ICaptureSource>`

This is behavior by design and as documented ("...automatically maintains a reference count for the underlying interface pointer..."). When your `captureSource` variable goes out of scope, there will be a reference count decrement on your object.

In your second approach you are attaching a raw interface pointer into `ComPtr` instance: you place a raw (meaning: not incremented by smart pointer class) pointer into `*ppv` so reference counter remains being one. `ComPtr` instance will have the pointer attached without increment, but it will decrement it on destruction. This is how the reference counter reaches zero.